# To hook into Git, would Ruby have an advantage over c#?

Tags: c#, git, api

If I wanted to be able to do all things GIT via C# i.e. creating a c# wrapper so I can do things over the web (view repositories, files, diff of files etc).

Would Ruby have any advantages over c# (and .net)?

Answer (score 2):

Not to answer your question directly but, have you seen http://code.google.com/p/gitsharp/ ?

Answer (score 2):

C# has  reputation of being easier to call into native code. However the vast majority of Git manipulation can be done with the "plumbing" commands and simple pipes; so I wouldn't think native code execution would be necessary for most needs.

Git is slightly more difficult to install on Windows; but that is a sunk cost and not a big deal, long-term. (You could also use Mono on Linux.)

So offhand, I would say no; the choice between C# vs. Ruby should come down to external factors such as which language you are stronger in, or which framework you prefer.

Comment: well I would be running the app on a windows box, but the GIT repos would be on linux.